# showing $\int_{0}^{1}x\sqrt{1+4x^2}\,dx=\int_{1}^{2}\sqrt{(2-y)+\frac{1}{4}}\,dy$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, substitution

How do we obtain $\int_{0}^{1}x\sqrt{1+4x^2}\,dx$ from $\displaystyle\int_{1}^{2}\sqrt{(2-y)+\frac{1}{4}}\,dy$ using $u$ substituition?

My approach :

Let $u^2=2-y$. Then $2u\,du=-dy$ and when $y=1$, $u=1$, and when $y=2$, $u=0$.

So
\begin{align}
\int_{1}^{2}\sqrt{(2-y)+\frac{1}{4}}\,dy&=\int_{1}^{0}\sqrt{u^2+\frac{1}{4}}(-2u)\,du\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}2u\sqrt{u^2+\frac{1}{4}}\, du\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}u\sqrt{4u^2+1}\,du\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}x\sqrt{4x^2+1}\,dx.
\end{align}

But is this kind of $u$-substitution possible?

I thought we usually substitute $u=$ something not $u^2=$ something.

Comment: Then is it a $u^2$-substitution?

Comment: Junpyo Choi,  Not very familiar with that term but you could sub $u=\sqrt{2-y}$ which is better which looks more like u substituition

Comment: note that subbing $u^2=2-y$ is that we could have $u=\pm \sqrt{2-y}$ which we do not want to have

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Thanks! Then $du=\frac{-1}{2\sqrt{2-y}}dy$ and I was wondering if it did not matter whether $\frac{-1}{2\sqrt{2-y}}$ is defined at the end points.

Comment: Why not set the two radicands equal to each other, and then solve for y?